# Add background to `standout` frame with Metropolis

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I'd like to set a background image for a `standout` frame in my Beamer presentation with Metropolis theme.

The meaning of adding the background is that it has transparencies, so it should appear like a filigrane to the coloured slide; however, when I add the image with `\usebackgroundtemplate{}`, background colour gets reverted to white (I can clearly see it from image transparency)

Is there a way to keep `standout` coloured slide but adding a transparent background image as well?

Here is a minimal MWE:

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[11pt, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
  {
    \usebackgroundtemplate{%
      \includegraphics[
        width=\paperwidth,
        height=\paperheight
      ]%
      {example-image}%
    }

    \begin{frame}[label = conclusion, standout]{Conclusion}
      Conclusion
    \end{frame}
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: As a workaround, I may use a painted background image with the same colour as the one of standout; however, I'd like to find a programmatic solution without having to rely on such dirty tricks and making presentation 'heavier'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `background` layer to add your image in front of the `background canvas`, which is used by the metropolis theme:

```
\documentclass[11pt, dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

  {
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a4}
    }

    \begin{frame}[label = conclusion, standout]{Conclusion}
      Conclusion
    \end{frame}
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]